# AutoCompletTextView Covered by dropdown view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Opening `dropdownView` of `autoCompleteTextView` in `ontouchlistener` by calling 
show DropDown but when its `clicked` DropDown opens. Then keyboard opens up, `autoCompleteTextView` moves up along with keyboard.

But dropdown view remains on its position when it was opened before opening of keyboard And before moving up of `autoCompleteTextView` due to keyboard opening. 
happening is `autoCompleteTextView` gets covered by Dropdown View and remaining Dropdown view gets covered by keyboard.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this for your activity in manifest.xml file:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
```

or

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
```

The `android:windowSoftInputMode` attribute can be used to specify what happens on a per-activity basis: whether the layout is resized or whether it scrolls etc.

you can also hide the soft keyboard when spinner is touched:

```
mSpinner.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            InputMethodManager imm=(InputMethodManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);  
            //here mEditText is your edittext where keyboard is shown before
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
            return false;
        }
    }) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

try the below code in mainfest

```
<activity
            android:name=".activity name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
 </activity>
```

and use this

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

in `onCreate()` of `Activity`